# Can't edit "/sys/devices/virtual/sound/timer/dev" file

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    private static final String SYSFS = "/sys/devices/virtual/sound/timer/dev";
    public void Place1() throws IOException {
        // Open the sysfs file for writing and write "116:33/34" to it.  
        PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(SYSFS));
        outStream.write("116:34");
        outStream.close();
    } 

}
```

I'm new at Java and Android development, so I'm writing this simple code to change a **dev** file but it seems to not work. The **dev** file has all -rw permissions. I tried to do it in a couple of ways, but every time it was unsuccessful.

**Note**: My phone is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String SYSFS = "/sys/devices/platform/omap3epfb.0/graphics/fb0/fmode"; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
            File file = new File(SYSFS);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("1");
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This works brilliant.
Maybe it was *PrintWriter* problem